# How to use pfstools to create OpenEXR files from command line on Linux/Mac?

Tags: software, hdr, linux

I'm trying to find a way to create OpenEXR (.exr) files using **pfstools** from—say—three bracketed JPEG exposures. I'm familiar with `enfuse` and other tools.

How can I create EXR files from the command line using Linux?

Answer (score 4):

Just guessing (I've never used pfstools, but I once maintained a man page set as a technical writer), you could probably use pipes and commands like the following example:

[`pfsinme`](http://pfstools.sourceforge.net/man1/pfsinme.1.html)`*.jpg |`[`pfshdrcalibrate`](http://pfstools.sourceforge.net/man1/pfshdrcalibrate.1.html) `-r linear -v |`[`pfsout`](http://pfstools.sourceforge.net/man1/pfsout.1.html)`result.exr`

This reads all the .jpg files in the current directory, merges them into an HDR image (with linear response) and saves the output as an Open EXR image.

See also: ["How do I use man pages to learn how to use commands?" on unix.SE.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193815)